# Add text field to poll entity

Tags: entities, 8

I have installed the Poll module in Drupal 8. I need to add a field to it, such as a text area for the poll description.

How can I add a field to a content entity like Poll, which is not a content type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poll is not a fieldable entity, so this is not possible in ui.

You can do this in code:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition;
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_base_field_info().
 */
function mymodule_entity_base_field_info(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() === 'poll') {
    $fields['description'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('text')
      ->setLabel(t('New discription field'))
      ->setTranslatable(TRUE);
    return $fields;
  }
}
```

Apply the schema update on the database:

```
drush entity-updates
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am having an error implementing it: Notice: Undefined index: description__value in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->loadFromSharedTables() (line 558 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).

Comment: Yeah it worked. Cleared cache and updated the entity type. There are problems with the display though - but thanks for pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: Ah, I must have totally dreamed making the field UI for poll accessible at /admin/config/content/poll then :) But yes, you an add fields, but they are by default not visible since viewing a poll is actually a form and doesn't use the standard entity render process. You can however alter the form and add things yourself.

Comment: I am glad that there is an UI. I in fact spent lots of time trying to find a work-around and also taking other people's time. If that UI followed the conventions and were easily discoverable, would be even better :(